# How to sort slice of an array in-place in F#

Tags: sorting, f#, slice

I want to sort a slice of an array, but the following code doesn't work as expected:

```ml
let arr = [|2; 8; 4; 1|]
Array.sortInPlace arr
printfn "%A" arr //1,2,4,8

let mutable arr2 = [|2; 8; 4; 1|]
Array.sortInPlace arr2.[1..]
printfn "%A" arr2.[1..] //8,4,1. Expected: 1,4,8
printfn "%A" arr2 //2,8,4,1. Expected: 2,1,4,8
```

The `mutable` keyword has no effect one way or the other.

How do I sort a continuous section of an array in-place in F#?

Comment: "doesn't work as expected"? What does that mean?

Comment: I improved the example. I want to sort the slice of the array in-place without making a copy of the array. The way it is, a copy of the array is ordered, not the array itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`System.MemoryExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions) to sort [`Spans`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1). Spans is a *view* around existing data that won't create any copies.

```ml
open System

let ar = [|2; 8; 4; 1|]
ar.AsSpan().Slice(1).Sort() // taking span of array, slicing from 1 index and sort remaining elements
printfn "%A" ar // [|2; 1; 4; 8|]
```

Note: this is supported only from net5

Comment: Also found [FSharp.Span.Utils](https://github.com/cannorin/FSharp.Span.Utils) library. Last update were in 2019. This library needs update (e.g. `sort` is not implemented), but can give you fsharp-style code like `ar |> Span.ofArray |> Span.skip 1 |> Span.sort`

Answer (score 2):

Solved by using `System.Array.Sort`. Using C# array instead of F#, but good enough I think.

```ml
let arr = [|2; 8; 1; 4|]
System.Array.Sort(arr, 1, arr.Length-1)
printfn "%A" arr //[|2; 1; 4; 8|]
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it doesn't appear to work is because you haven't bound the slice to a name. From the compiler's perspective, the slice in the `sortInPlace` call is different from the slice where you print some contents.

Bind the slice to a name like so and it will behave as you expect it to:

```
let arr2 = [|2; 8; 4; 1|]
let slice = arr2.[1..]
Array.sortInPlace slice
printfn "%A" slice
```

Comment: This order a copy of arr2 (the slice), not arr2. I want to order a slice of arr2 in-place.